# with gettranslation how doI get the user of the most recent revision

Tags: 8, nodes

I am using `$node->getTranslation('language')` to get all of the information in the translation object.

I want to know how I can get the user id of the most RECENT revision of this translation.

I can get the title and the fields like this below but don't know how to get the creator of the most recent revision:
          `$translation = $node->getTranslation($translang);
      $title = $translation->title->value ;
       $audience = $translation->get('field_pup_audience')->target_id;`

Comment: Have you tried using [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) with kint to inspect the object?

Comment: I can't use devel or kint because this is a cron script so devel and kint don't work.  any other suggestions? thanks

Comment: Use Devel's "Execute PHP" block  (assign it to a region) and load up the object here and inspect with kint.